# Uno Platform Dock Panel

Tags: uno-platform

Is there a Dock Panel for Uno? I have installed the uno.microsoft.uwp.ui.controls (v. 7.1.0) nuget package but I cannot seem to find a Dock Panel. Below is the only xmlns I can use to get any type of controls from the package.

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Layout"
```

When I look in the nuget package folder for the uno.microsoft.uwp.ui.controls there is a _._ file in the netstandard1.0 folder and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looking throgh all of the nuget folders I found the primitives folder that contained DockPanel.

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Primitives"
```

Answer (score -1):

To expand on your answer - you can simplify the syntax as follows:

```
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
```

As the control itself is in the `Controls` namespace directly, only the assembly is `Primitives`. To reference it, install the following [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Primitives/7.1.0-build.2.g0e224f133a):

```
Install-Package Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Primitives -Version 7.1.0-build.2.g0e224f133a
```

In XAML you can then just use:

```
<controls:DockPanel ... />
```

Comment: if I use your xmlns then I have no intillisince for any controls. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: As long as you choose UWP as the target platform in the top left dropdown in the code window, you should get the proper IntelliSense